# Can I add service name aliases in K8s DNS the same way links can have aliases in Docker?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

In Docker a client container can refer to a server container by different names by using link aliasing:

```
--link server-container:my_preferred_server
```

A second client can use its own choice of names

```
-- link server-container:server
```

Can I achieve this in K8s preferably by adding different records in K8s's DNS?

**Note** the solution we are using now is having the client containers not use a hardcoded name for the server container, but use the value of an env variable SERVER_HOSTNAME='server-container' and link without aliasing:

```
--link server_container
```

**Edit:** To answer to some of the questions got in the replies:
* there is more than one client container, otherwise aliasing would have no purpose. Each client knows the server by a different name
* the client and the server are not in the same pod

Comment: Do the containers that need to talk to each other reside on the same pod?

Comment: Have you tried to just add another service of a different name that selects the same pod? Also, if you're familiar with kubernetes services and have kube DNS setup, then none of these should be problems you need to solve.

Comment: @Yaron different pods

Comment: @iamnat adding another service will come with its own port definitions and at least another instance of the container, while all I want is name aliasing.

Comment: Adding another service will not require another instance, the servicea merely register pods, they dont create any.

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same need and I was able to add an external Service, which points to the FQDN of the other service within the cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "my-alias"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: "other-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local"
```

Now, I can access `other-service` as `my-alias` from within the cluster and namespace.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for: it works perfectly. It's weird there is not a native way to define a "service alias name", could be an useful option

Comment: The `name` does not support adding dots `.`, which does not really make this a very reliable solution. Do you suggest any solution for this limitation? This is especially important in case I already have certificates for particular domain(s).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve that.

- You can simply create a **Service** for the server container (in its own **Pod**), if the **Pod** is in the same Kubernetes cluster then a typical **Service** will do, if the server container is outside of Kubernetes, you can create a Service with `ExternalIPs` to define the IPs of the endpoints
- If this is side-by-side deployment (i.e. 1 client <-> 1 server) you might consider keeping the client and server in the same **Pod** definition: in a single Pod, the client container can reach the server container via `localhost` on its specific port.
- You can fiddle with kube-dns to inject arbitrary dns names (or even overwrite public ones), but you should really not have to do this.